# How to catch exception in uploading file - zend framework 1

Tags: php, oop, zend-framework, exception

I am trying to catch the exception while uploading file in zend framework 1.

I denied permission to  the folder and then ran the following code to catch the exception but it is not working.

```
public function uploadImage($postedFile,$destination) {
        try {
              $imageName = $this->getFileName($postedFile); //$postedFile is same as $_FILES


        $upload = new Zend_File_Transfer();

        foreach ($upload->getFileInfo($imageName) as $info) {

            if ($info['name'] != '') {
                $ext = pathinfo($info['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
                $newName = md5(rand(1, 100).date('ymdhis') . $info['name']) . '.' . $ext;

                $upload->addFilter('Rename', $destination."/".$newName);
                if (!$upload->receive($info['name'])) {
                    return FALSE;
                }

            }
            break;
        }
          return $newName;
        } catch (Zend_File_Transfer_Exception $e) {
            throw new Exception('I want to catch this'); 
        }

    }
```

error:

```
    Warning: 
move_uploaded_file(/var/www/html/glistonapp/application/../public/images/app_user_profile_picture/80d55d25c52ef4d74079cfa903288b77.png): 
failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/html/glistonapp/library/Zend/File/Transfer/Adapter/Http.php on line 189 
Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phpOtOLVv' to '/var/www/html/glistonapp/application/../public/images/app_user_profile_picture/80d55d25c52ef4d74079cfa903288b77.png' in /var/www/html/glistonapp/library/Zend/File/Transfer/Adapter/Http.php on line 189
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't appear that the methods you are calling on the `Zend_File_Transfer` object will throw an exception.

Without a thrown exception, you won't be able to "catch" anything in your try block.  Instead, you should check the return values of the functions you are calling to determine if there was a problem.

See the API reference which will tell you which methods throw exceptions:
http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/1.12/classes/Zend_File_Transfer_Adapter_Abstract.html

Comment: thanks for your reply. I have also tried something like this :

try {
    //code
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    echo $ex->getMessage();exit;// not working
}
 but it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Your error message is not an exception, therefore it won't be caught by the try/catch block.

You should set the appropriate permissions on the destination directory for that error message.